# Enable Button If all the checkboxes are ticked

Tags: excel, vba, button, checkbox

I have a vba code that has been assigned to a button named as "run report". Have some instructions with check boxes and what I am trying to do is to enable button only if all the checkboxes are ticked. I tried something like below but somehow it's not working. It seems something is wrong with declaration. I am using ms office 2013 version.

```
Sub buttonenable()
Dim B1 as Button
Dim C1 as Checkbox
Dim C2 as Checkbox
Dim C3 as Checkbox
Set B1 = Thisworkbook.Sheets("Home").Button("Run report")
Set C1 = Thisworkbook.Sheets("Home").Checkbox("Checkbox1")

Set C2 = Thisworkbook.Sheets("Home").Checkbox("Checkbox2")

Set C3 = Thisworkbook.Sheets("Home").Checkbox("Checkbox3")

IF C1 = True and C2 = True and C3 = True Then
B1.Enable = True

Else
B1.enable = False

End If

End Sub()
```

Comment: Please Use "Option Explicit" at the top of your code. Better yet tick all the boxes in Tools>Options>Editor. This will show the errors in your declarations and some code, for instance the capitalisation of Button, Checkbox, and, thisworkbook being spelled wrong. If you type it in lowercase and it corrects to being capitalised, then vba has "recognised" it.

Comment: I'm not in front of a pc I can try this on, but I believe "Enabled" is the button property you're after. Go into "design mode", right click on the button, and click Properties to check this and see the other properties too (also, make sure the "Name" there matches the button name in your code.) I can see it's not been "recognised" towards the end of your code.

Comment: Also, buttons and checkboxes aren't as simple as in your code... from memory they are Shapes or Forms depending on if they are an ActiveX or Form control.

Comment: @Stax is on to it. `YourControl.Enabled` is the correct syntax, and it is different access to the properties depending on if they are Form controls or ActiveX.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub ButtonEnable()
   Dim ws As Worksheet

   Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")

   If ws.OLEObjects("chkbox1").Object.Value And _
      ws.OLEObjects("chkbox2").Object.Value Then
      ws.OLEObjects("CommandButton1").Object.Enabled = True
   Else
      ws.OLEObjects("CommandButton1").Object.Enabled = False
   End If

   Set ws = Nothing
End Sub
```

You also have to have a click event for each checkbox that points to this ButtonEnable.
For example:

```
Private Sub chkbox1_Click()
   ButtonEnable
End Sub

Private Sub chkbox2_Click()
   ButtonEnable
End Sub
```

I assume that you are using ActiveX Controls.